# SDL2 - Crash when trying to copy surface information to structure. No error message given

Tags: c, crash, sdl, sdl-2

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    SDL_Texture *texture; // The image/sprite itself
    int width;            // Sprite width
    int height;           // Sprite height
} Sprite;

Sprite *createSprite(SDL_Renderer *r, char *path);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    // Initialise SDL and SDL_image
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);

    // Create window
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "VN",                   // Title
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, // Initial x position
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, // Initial y position
        1280,                   // Width
        720,                    // Height
        0                       // Flags
    );

    if(window == NULL){
        printf("Failed to create window. %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Create renderer
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(
        window,                     // Window
        -1,                         // Monitor index (-1 for first available)
        SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED    // Flags
    );

    if(renderer == NULL){
        printf("Failed to create renderer. %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Set up event handling
    SDL_Event event;

    while(1){
        // Handle events/input
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0){
            // Check if user wants to quit (press window close button)
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT){
                return 1;
            }
        }

        // Set screen colour to white
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        // Render white to screen (clear screen)
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        // Update screen
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    // Exit SDL and SDL_image
    SDL_Quit();
    IMG_Quit();
    return 0;
}

Sprite *createSprite(SDL_Renderer *r, char *path){
    printf("Entered createSprite()\n");

    // Create a Sprite structure, containing an image (texture) and its dimensions
    Sprite *newSprite = NULL;
    SDL_Texture *spriteTexture = NULL;

    // Temporary surface (for loading texture)
    SDL_Surface *tempSurface = NULL;

    // Load image from path
    tempSurface = IMG_Load(path);
    if(tempSurface == NULL){
        printf("Failed to load image '%s'. %s\n", path, IMG_GetError());
    } else{
        spriteTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(r, tempSurface);
        if(spriteTexture == NULL){
            printf("Failed to create texture from '%s'. %s\n", path, SDL_GetError());
        } else{
            // Store texture, image width & height in Sprite structure
            newSprite->texture = spriteTexture;
            newSprite->width = tempSurface->w;
            newSprite->height = tempSurface->h;
        }
    }

    // Free memory of temp surface
    SDL_FreeSurface(tempSurface);

    printf("Leaving createSprite()\n");
    return newSprite;
}
```

I'm attempting to load an image using the SDL_image addon, and store its width and height in a structure (along with a texture created from the surface).

It crashes when attempting to run the `newSprite->texture = spriteTexture;` section on Line 93. That's as much information as I can give I'm afraid. Any ideas?

I'm attempting to load an image using the SDL_image addon, and store its width and height in a structure (along with a texture created from the surface).

Comment: So where does 'newSprite' get set to anything aside from NULL? That is, where does this program allocate memory for the Sprite structure? A NULL reference will crash for sure.

Comment: @jhc I'm a complete twit, thank you.

Comment: Where do you even call `createSprite()` from `main()`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're not allocating memory for `Sprite` in your `createSprite` function. You set it to NULL and than try to access that location which of course fails.

Try this:

```
Sprite *createSprite(SDL_Renderer *r, char *path){
    printf("Entered createSprite()\n");

    // Create a Sprite structure, containing an image (texture) and its dimensions
    Sprite *newSprite = new Sprite();   //<<- this is where you allocate the memory
    SDL_Texture *spriteTexture = NULL;

    // Temporary surface (for loading texture)
    SDL_Surface *tempSurface = NULL;

    // Load image from path
    tempSurface = IMG_Load(path);
    if(tempSurface == NULL){
        printf("Failed to load image '%s'. %s\n", path, IMG_GetError());
    } else{
        spriteTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(r, tempSurface);
        if(spriteTexture == NULL){
            printf("Failed to create texture from '%s'. %s\n", path, SDL_GetError());
        } else{
            // Store texture, image width & height in Sprite structure
            newSprite->texture = spriteTexture;
            newSprite->width = tempSurface->w;
            newSprite->height = tempSurface->h;
        }
    }

    // Free memory of temp surface
    SDL_FreeSurface(tempSurface);

    printf("Leaving createSprite()\n");
    return newSprite;
}
```